# Looping through XMLs in folder using openrowset / "Must declare the scalar variable" Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openrowset

Essentially I am trying to use SQL to query XML files within a folder. The code to query the XML works fine on its own but once I turned it into a string to allow for expressions in 'openrowset' it keeps saying throwing out an error message saying it cannot find @x and that 'Must declare the scalar variable'. I understand there is also sp_executesql but I don't really understand how that works and why it would be needed.

Thanks in advance!

```
drop table #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp(files VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /B "C:\Users\USER\A\B"';


While (Select Count(*) From #tmp where files is not null) > 0
Begin

DECLARE @fileName varchar(max)
DECLARE @filepath varchar(max)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Select Top 1 @fileName = files From #tmp

Set @filepath = 'C:\Users\USER\990\A\B\' + @filename

DECLARE @n1 varchar(max)
DECLARE @n2 varchar(max)

Set @n1 = 'http://www.namespace1.com/file'
Set @n2 ='http://www.namespac2.com/XMLSchema'



SET @sql = '
DECLARE @x xml

@x = R
FROM Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @filepath + ''' , Single_Blob) AS ReturnData(R);
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT '''+@n1+'''
                          ,'''+@n2+''' AS xsi)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[IRS]
           ([A]
           ,[B]
           ,[C]
           )
     Select
       ct.value('''+'(../../Data/A/)[1]'+''','''+'varchar(max)'+''')
      ,ct.value('''+'(../../Data/B)[1]'+''','''+'varchar(max)'+''') 
      ,ct.value('''+'(../../Data/C/)[1]'+''','''+'varchar(max)'+''') 

FROM @x.nodes('''+'/Return/ReturnData/IRS990ScheduleH'+''') AS A(ct)
'

exec(@sql)
Delete from #tmp Where files = @FileName

End
```

Comment: `DECLARE @x xml; /* need a SELECT here */ @x = R` - `PRINT @sql;` is usually a pretty effective debugging technique.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, the @sql part worked fine when it was its own query but now that it is dynamic it is not working well (saying that X is not declared). And thanks, I used PRINT for debugging and things seem fine.

Comment: It can't possibly work as written, dynamic or not. `DECLARE @x xml @x = R FROM...` is simply completely invalid syntax. Your static query that is working must look slightly different.

Comment: Ahh gotchya, yes you are right, I missed adding 'SELECT @x = R' in my posting but that was present in my query. My apologizes for missing that. The issue still remains.

Comment: Your last edit introduced the word `select` before `@x = R`. This is the suggestion you got from two sides... Does it work now?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you and Shnugo were right, I thought it was a posting error but  I did miss that select. My apologizes. Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error happens here:

```
DECLARE @x xml

@x = Something
```

Either use

```
DECLARE @x XML=SomeXml;
or
DECLARE @x XML=(SELECT SomeXml FROM SomeWhere);
```

or

```
DECLARE @x xml;
```

and then either

```
SET @x=SomeXml;
or
SET @x=(SELECT SomeXml FROM SomeWhere);
or
SELECT @x=SomeXml FROM SomeWhere;
```

Comment: Thanks, right now it is "@x = R
FROM Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @filepath + ''' , Single_Blob) AS ReturnData(R)" so that part was working fine before I turned it into a dynamic query.

Comment: @riyadude I doubt that this was working. Try `DECLARE @x XML; SELECT @x=R FROM ...` the word `SELECT` should make the difference...

Comment: The error I continue to get is "Msg 102
Incorrect syntax near '@x'.
and Msg 137
Must declare the scalar variable "@x".

Comment: @riyadude With dynamic SQL it is a very good idea to use `PRINT @sql` then copy the written text into a new query window and check for syntax errors... Did you try this?

Comment: oh my, no you both were right, I did missed that select, looked in the wrong place initially. Thank you!